# convert string date and time to utc based on timezone using moment

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs, moment-timezone

am using moment in nodejs server to convert local time from frontend to utc.

my time format is `date = '10-07-2020 08:45 PM'` in string format. When i use `moment(date).format()` its converting format to this `2020-10-07 20:45:00+05:30` timezone is adding based on server and i have `timezone = '+4:00'` this is my local timezone. I would like to convert my date string to UTC based on the `timezone` field not based on the server timezone. How can I do this?

I tried the following methods but am not getting a proper solution

```
moment.utc(moment(date).utcOffset(timezone)).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
```

Anyone Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

You can use [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) to create a date from a string and a certain timezone. In order to do that you need to specify your format and the corresponding timezone. Something like this:

```js
const date = moment.tz("10-07-2020 08:45 pm", "M-D-YYYY hh:mm a", "Europe/Samara");
console.log(date.toISOString());
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @op: If this solved your issue, please accept the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of moment, perhaps use [intl DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat)?

Here are some possibilities

```js
const options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric',  hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric', };

const date = new Date('10-07-2020 08:45 PM')
console.log(date)


options.timeZone = 'Europe/Ulyanovsk';
options.timeZoneName = 'short';
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', options).format(date));
```